# Coredata helper

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

So I am creating an app in the form of a social media app. I am using the tutorial found [here](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/) as a springboard since I am still trying to wrap my brain around Core Data. I've deviated from the tutorial by adding a sign up button that takes the user to a new View Controller and created a .h and a .m file and set the New Member screen to reference the .h and .m files. They are set up as follows for the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewMemberViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTF;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ageTF;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTF;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTF;

- (IBAction)alreadyMember:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)checkAndLogin:(id)sender;


@end
```

and for the .m:

```
#import "NewMemberViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"

@interface NewMemberViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewMemberViewController

@synthesize usernameTF, ageTF, passwordTF, nameTF, managedObjectContext;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//If the user is already a member simply dismiss the VC
- (IBAction)alreadyMember:(id)sender {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

//When done editing keyboard
- (IBAction)checkAndLogin:(id)sender {
managedObjectContext =self.managedObjectContext;

//Textfield Reference
UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)sender;

//Check tag numbers If its equal to 1 or 2(nameTF or ageTF) then
if (tf.tag==1||tf.tag==2)
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"This is working");
}
//If its equal to 3 then this means the username text field is active
else if (tf.tag == 3)
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    //do a quick search to see if username is availible
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username == %@)", [usernameTF text]];

    //Run the query to check if user exists
    if([CoreDataHelper countForEntity:@"Users" withPredicate:pred andContext:managedObjectContext] > 0)
    {
        //we found a user
        NSLog(@"oh no...");
    }
  }
}
@end
```

With that being said if I run my app and go to the signup screen and test to see if the user exists, by typing in admin because it already exists, i get the following error in Xcode:

> Canvases[779:11603] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate:   +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Users'

What does this mean and why is it being caused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you pass the context to the view controller? Try with:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
yourVontext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

before fetch.

Comment: For this to work would I need to import anything in the .h file?

Comment: Wanted to say thank you. I added this to the top of my 'checkAndLogin' action and then ran it and my app worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with below line.

```
managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

`self.managedObjectContext` is returning nil to `managedObjectContext`. Instead of self.managedObjectContext you should create Core Data Stack (method implementation)in the Application Delegate and then pass object reference of ManagedObjectContext from AppDelegate to your caller class.

Comment: I have a core data stack that is set up in AppDelegate, but how would I go about passing object reference?

Comment: @joeBustamante I guess you got answer of your question above.